# cmd append to file > extra space in the end

Tags: windows, cmd

```
set NUMBER=0

echo 3.3.3.%NUMBER% > "file.txt"
```

after running this command the content of `file.txt` is `3.3.3.0` with extra space after the `0`

I would like to remove the extra space, how this can be done?

**EDIT**

I following the answer of `bgoldst` the extra space is gone, however now I have extra line break. I want to remove it

I found some answers for solving the extra line, however I don't want space not new line in the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using echo without trailing space in DOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505552/using-echo-without-trailing-space-in-dos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answer by [bgoldst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4272464/bgoldst)

To remove the `space` **and** the `line feed`:

```
<nul set /p=3.3.3.%NUMBER%>file.txt
```

See [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line) for more information.

Comment: But this has a space in the end... I want no space nor new line

Comment: @user829174 Answer modified to remove both.

Answer (score 1):

The space is introduced by the `echo` command because there is a space between the `%NUMBER%` variable and the `>` redirection operator. The `echo` command respects trailing whitespace in its command-line.

Thus, you can solve this by removing that space (and you can also remove the quotes, as well as the space between the `>` and the `file.txt`, since they are not necessary):

```
echo 3.3.3.%NUMBER%>file.txt
```

Comment: Good, it removed the extra space but there is also a line break, how can I remove it?