# CMD/BATCH BAT SCRIPT How to add digit to file without space

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i want to make a start.config file by using bat script.
I want to add to my config file that parameter:

```
StartAgents=9
```

WITHOUT space at the end of line.

Unfortunately command:

```
echo StartAgents=9>>C:\start.config
```

not working, I think that there is "collision" with two characters: "9>"

Command:

```
echo StartAgents=9 >>C:\start.config
```

is working, but this is adding space at the end of line in my config file - i dont want that.

Any ideas how to do that?

I want to add line StartAgents=9 without space af the end of line.
want:

```
StartAgents=9
```

dont want:

```
StartAgents=9
```

Comment: `1>>C:\start.config (echo StartAgents=9)`

Comment: You are trying to echo Stream9 (which is empty) to the file. Use `>file echo 9` or `(echo 9) > file`  (where `>` is just an abbreviation of the correct form `1>` / `[StreamID]>`)

Comment: @Stephan Yes! I totally forgot about that one - obligatory [oldnewthing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170731-00/?p=96715).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the number, so that it isn't interpreted by CMD.EXE as a file descriptor number.

Then you can add the `>>` redirection directly after the number to not insert a trailing space.

Example:

```
echo StartAgent=^9>>test.txt
```

Related Information:

- [Omitting trailing space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505552/using-echo-without-trailing-space-in-dos)
- [File Descriptor Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20484234/21567)

Comment: Make sure you also consider @Stephan's comment. The notation to put the redirection _before_ the `echo` is actually quite useful too (I totally forgot that one ;-))